# Windows 11 Stops Looking for Face in Facial Recognition

Tags: windows-11, windows-hello

I have Windows 11 facial recognition turned on.  If Windows fails to recognize me because I am away, then it switches to wanting my pin.  It is annoying to click on "Sign-in options" and then the face icon so that Windows will look for my face again.  How do I get Windows to always look for my face and require me to click on "Sign-in options" if I want to use a different sign in option.

Windows 11 version 22H2 build 22621.963
Alienware Area-51m R2

Answer (score 0):

Windows 11 Settings.

Accounts, Sign In Options.

Remove the Fingerprint / Facial recognition (but NOT the PIN).

Restart the computer.

Set up Facial recognition again and test.

Also update the bio recognition driver.

If your machine has hardware diagnostics, run these to ensure there is not a hardware issue  (seem less likely).

If it works now, then you will have to use it as Microsoft has designed.

Comment: These instructions seem to be for fixing facial recognition when it isn't working.  Is that correct?  Facial recognition is working.  If it doesn't detect my face, then Windows switches to entering a pin.  I have to manually tell it to look for my face.  This is an annoyance but otherwise it works.

Comment: We want to be sure your facial recognition works - hence the instructions. Just to check.  Otherwise, if working then that is all you can do and must use it the way designed.

Comment: My facial recognition works; otherwise, I wouldn't be able to go through the steps to login using my face after clicking on the face icon.